# Starting a YouTube channel - Advise/Questions/Tips

Tags: video, youtube, tutorial

everyone. I want to start a YouTube channel with some Computer Science and Mathematics tutorials and would want to hear your opinions/advice on how to get on about it.

**So, here is what I want to do:**

1. Ideally, I would want my videos to be similar to Khan Academy's tutorial style/Organic Chemistry Tutor's tutorial style for maths. This is because I am not really comfortable showing my face and doing calculations on a whiteboard.  So, I want to be able to write on a screen.
2. For Computer Science, I want to switch in between writing code, and/or slides and the board where I write all my content.

**These are my questions:**

1. I have an iPad and a Macbook. What software can I use to record my videos for the written portion/coding portion?
2. I don't have any experience in editing videos. So what skills should I familiarize myself with in order to be able to make videos that people can hopefully understand?

Comment: It would be nice if you put an example of the video you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad, but here are some tips.

If it is like this one

you could start with a nice PowerPoint presentation... Nicer than that example.

> So what skills should I familiarize myself

There are three main categories.

**1. Videos with significant production value.**

Animation, photography, Illumination, music, voice, good quality, a script, storyboard, revisions...

Because of the big effort it represents, the scripting part (and its revisions) are of paramount importance.

Introduction, development, climax, conclusion.

**2. Live recorded tutorials**

As you remember to do things, with bloopers and fixed later with some annotation over the video.

**3. Anything in between**

---

> I don't have any experience in editing videos... videos that people can hopefully understand?

Simply make them suited to your target.

This is not related directly to editing video, it is related to your capacity to make your explanations understandable but mainly interesting. It is related to what draws attention to the intended audience.

We live in a competitive era. There are a lot of videos with good quality. Some rely on personal charisma, some on the production, some in the style, some on a ton of other things.

Define what is your "mojo". What is the thing you are going to do to differentiate and add value to your product?

Yes, some of that is given by the editing. The editing is meant to give you rhythm. Some parts are meant to give you unity, volume to the voice, volume to the music.

But any editing is not enough if your source material is not good. So...

Simply prepare a video like if you are preparing a good exposition to a live audience.